# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: user_id (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR):

Tags: database, sqlite, android-studio, authentication

being an Android Studio beginner i tend to get lots and lots of tiny errors i cannot find out, please let me know what I am doing wrong because I've tried all the other answers somehow and it doesn't get better :)

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UserManager.db";

    private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";

    private static final String COLUMN_USER_ID= "user_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_NAME= "user_name";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_EMAIL= "user_email";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD= "user_password";

    private String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "(" + 
    COLUMN_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
    + COLUMN_USER_NAME + " TEXT," + COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " TEXT," + 
    COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT" + ")";

    private String DROP_USER_TABLE = " DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context){

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        db.execSQL(DROP_USER_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addUser(User user){
        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_NAME, user.getName());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_EMAIL, user.getEmail());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD, user.getPassword());


        db.insert(TABLE_USER,null, values);
        db.close();


    }

    public boolean checkUser(String password, String email){
        String[] columns = {
                COLUMN_USER_ID
        };
        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
        String selection = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " = ? " + "AND "+ COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD+" =? ";
        String[] selectionArgs = { email,password };

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER,
                columns,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                null,
                null,
                null);
        int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        if(cursorCount > 0){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
     }
}
```

I know the logcat let me know this:

```
07-11 22:08:29.072 9071-9071/com.example.lavinia.sqllogin E/AndroidRuntime: 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.lavinia.sqllogin, PID: 9071
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: user_id (code 1 
SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_email = 
?AND user_password =?
```

And I can't find the wrong usage of *user_id*, I think I used it fine and the app will stop working after I Login myself. (the app has login and registration activities- and the registration works ok, but pressing the Login button in the Login.activity will make the app crash)

Thank you very much for you support :) If needed, I will provide with further code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is probably due to ***i tend to get lots and lots of tiny errors*** in conjunction with a common misconception regarding the `onCreate` method.

The `onCreate` method automatically runs only once when the database is and **has actually been created**. It does not run every time the App is run.

As such any changes (corrections included) to the structure (tables and columns) will not be applied if they are coded/actioned within the `onCreate` method.

When developing the easiest fix is to do one of the following 3:-

- delete the App's data (deletes the database so `onCreate` will be called).
- uninstall the App (deletes the database so `onCreate` will be called).
- if the `onUpgrade` method will drop the table(s) and then call `onCreate` , to increase the database version number as passed as the 4th parameter to the SQLIteOpenHelper sub-class (aka the DatabaseHelper class).

After doing one of the above, rerun the App.

#### NOTE any existing data will be lost.

- If data has to be retained then a fix is more complicated but would be based upon using ALTER TABLE statements.

Comment: Thank you kind sir :) It all worked out somehow when reproducing the steps.. now all I get after registration and trying to log in : Email or password wrong.. There is a new error, time to be angry about the new one now :D