# Wrong password/email error authentication activity - with SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite, authentication, android-sqlite

What can be wrong with the Onclick() method? Or verifyFromSqlite()? Trying to login with data just provided to the registration form, why the output of pressing Login button is just an error that the password/email is wrong?

```
 public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private final AppCompatActivity activity = LoginActivity.this;

private NestedScrollView nestedScrollView;

private TextInputLayout textInputLayoutEmail;
private TextInputLayout textInputLayoutPassword;

private TextInputEditText textInputEditTextEmail;
private TextInputEditText textInputEditTextPassword;

private AppCompatButton appCompatButtonLogin;

private AppCompatTextView textViewLinkRegister;

private InputValidation inputValidation;
private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();


    initViews();
    initListeners();
    initObjects();


}
private void initViews(){
    nestedScrollView = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.nestedScrollView);

    textInputLayoutEmail= (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutEmail);
    textInputLayoutPassword= (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutPassword);

    textInputEditTextEmail=(TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextEmail);
    textInputEditTextPassword=(TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextPassword);

    appCompatButtonLogin = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.appCompatButtonLogin);
    textViewLinkRegister= (AppCompatTextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLinkRegister);
}

private void initListeners(){
    appCompatButtonLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    textViewLinkRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void initObjects(){
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(activity);
    inputValidation = new InputValidation(activity);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.appCompatButtonLogin:
            verifyFromSQLite();
            break;

        case R.id.textViewLinkRegister:
            Intent intentRegister = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentRegister);
            break;
    }
}

private void verifyFromSQLite(){
    if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextEmail, textInputLayoutEmail, getString(R.string.error_message_email))){
        return;

    }
    if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextEmail(textInputEditTextEmail, textInputLayoutEmail, getString(R.string.error_message_email))){
        return;
    }

    if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextPassword, textInputLayoutPassword, getString(R.string.error_message_password))){
        return;
    }

    if(databaseHelper.checkUser(textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim()
            , textInputEditTextPassword.getText().toString().trim())){
        Intent accountsIntent = new Intent(activity, UsersActivity.class);
        accountsIntent.putExtra("EMAIL", textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim());
        emptyInputEditText();
        startActivity(accountsIntent);
    } else {
        Snackbar.make(nestedScrollView, getString(R.string.error_valid_email_password), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private void emptyInputEditText(){
    textInputEditTextEmail.setText(null);
    textInputEditTextPassword.setText(null);
}
}
```

This right here will do the wrong thing I believe.

```
 if(databaseHelper.checkUser(textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim()
            , textInputEditTextPassword.getText().toString().trim())){
        Intent accountsIntent = new Intent(activity, UsersActivity.class);
        accountsIntent.putExtra("EMAIL", textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim());
        emptyInputEditText();
        startActivity(accountsIntent);
    } else {
        Snackbar.make(nestedScrollView, getString(R.string.error_valid_email_password), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

please let me know what I am doing wrong because I've tried all the other answers and it won't click to me :) Why would error message me after registration and trying to log in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the **`checkUser`** method is unchanged from your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51295071/android-database-sqlite-sqliteexception-no-such-column-user-id-code-1-sqlite/51297704#51297704) i.e. it is :-

```
public boolean checkUser(String password, String email){
    String[] columns = {
            COLUMN_USER_ID
    };
    SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
    String selection = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " = ? " + "AND "+ COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD+" =? ";
    String[] selectionArgs = { email,password };

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER,
            columns,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null,
            null,
            null);
    int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    if(cursorCount > 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
 }
```

Then you are passing the email as the password and the password as the email. Try changing :-

```
if(databaseHelper.checkUser(textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim()
            , textInputEditTextPassword.getText().toString().trim())){
        Intent accountsIntent = new Intent(activity, UsersActivity.class);
        accountsIntent.putExtra("EMAIL", textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim());
        emptyInputEditText();
        startActivity(accountsIntent);
    } else {
        Snackbar.make(nestedScrollView, getString(R.string.error_valid_email_password), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

to :-

```
if(databaseHelper.checkUser( textInputEditTextPassword.getText().toString().trim()
            ,textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim())){
        Intent accountsIntent = new Intent(activity, UsersActivity.class);
        accountsIntent.putExtra("EMAIL", textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim());
        emptyInputEditText();
        startActivity(accountsIntent);
    } else {
        Snackbar.make(nestedScrollView, getString(R.string.error_valid_email_password), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: No sir, it won't work, and I think you posted the exact same code to change. Is there any change, because I can't see it? There is the same email or password wrong.. it won't save my registration data..

Comment: @LaviniaRotaru the difference is that the first parameter to the call to the `checkUser` method is the password (`textInputEditTextPassword.getText().toString().trim()`) not the email, the email (`textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim()`) is the 2nd parameter as opposed to the password as the `checkUser` method has a signature of **password, email** not email,password.